# Override not working on prestashop 1.7 Category class

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.7

Why is prestashop don't save my modification into database? 
I've done an override on the Category.php (prestashop 1.7) class file, here is my code:

/override/classes/Category.php

class Category extends CategoryCore
{
    /**
    * afficher/masquer les produits
    */
    public $show_products = 1;
    public $andrana;

```
public function __construct($idCategory = null, $idLang = null, $idShop = null)
{
    $definition = self::$definition;

    $definition['fields']['show_products'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'required' => true);
    $definition['fields']['andrana'] = array(
        'type' => self::TYPE_HTML,
        'lang' => true,
        'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'
    );
    parent::__construct($idCategory, $idLang, $idShop);
}
```

}

/override\controllers\admin\AdminCategoriesController.php

class AdminCategoriesController extends AdminCategoriesControllerCore
{

```
public function renderForm()
{
    $this->fields_form_override = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'switch',
            'label' => $this->trans('Afficher les produits', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            'name' => 'show_products',
            'required' => false,
            'is_bool' => true,
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'active_on',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => $this->trans('Enabled', array(), 'Admin.Global')
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'active_off',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'label' => $this->trans('Disabled', array(), 'Admin.Global')
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'label' => $this->trans('Andrana', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            'name' => 'andrana',
            'autoload_rte' => true,
            'lang' => true,
            'hint' => $this->trans('Invalid characters:', array(), 'Admin.Notifications.Info').' <>;=#{}'
        ),
    );
    return parent::renderForm();
}
```

}

PS: I've added "show_products" on ps_category table and "andrana" in ps_category_lang table

Please help me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the __construct to:

```
public function __construct($idCategory = null, $idLang = null, $idShop = null)
{

    self::$definition['fields']['show_products'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'required' => true);
    self::$definition['fields']['andrana'] = array(
        'type' => self::TYPE_HTML,
        'lang' => true,
        'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'
    );
    parent::__construct($idCategory, $idLang, $idShop);
}
```